# Using JavaScript to process and rearrange a plain text nested list

Tags: javascript, list, rhino, text-parsing

I have a plain-text data file which contains a nested list of items, like so:

```
Group: Folder
    Group: Subfolder1
    Group: Subfolder2
Group: Folder2
    Group: Subfolder1
        Group: NestedSubfolder1
```

...and so on. (Every folder name has "Group: " prepended to it in the list automatically; there's also no naming structure or convention for the folders, I labeled them as such to *try* to avoid complicating the example) This file is updated frequently, so manual modification of it isn't an option, and I don't have control over how the output is arranged/formatted.

The application I'm using which reads this file processes it as a massive (the source is about four thousand lines long) single line of text with no line breaks or separators/delimiters, so it ends up looking like this:

```
Group: Folder        Group: Subfolder1        Group: Subfolder2    Group: Folder2        Group: Subfolder1            Group: NestedSubfolder
```

Now, here's my problem. The way it needs to be formatted in order to use it is as such:

```
Folder/Subfolder1
Folder/Subfolder2
Folder2/Subfolder1/NestedSubfolder1
```

For my normal use cases, RegEx or some other clever filtering allows me to get the info I need, but since this has no delimiters, line breaks, or separators, and requires text to be copied and intelligently pasted into place automatically, I'm at a bit of a loss. The application being used to parse through this data and act upon it can run JavaScript (Rhino) scriptlets, so it is theoretically possible to have the application run a script which converts the output into properly-formatted, usable plain text. However, I'm not yet proficient (at all) with JS; has anyone had to tackle a similar task, or have any clever ideas to process this type of list so that each item contains the full path to it?

Comment: With the exception of the first folder, it looks like it breaks down as follows: every folder is has 4 characters of space before it, every subfolder has 8 and every nested subfolder has 12. They increase by 4 every time. So have you tried using regex to add a line break after each folder name then parsed by amount of white space on each line ?

Comment: replace newline+tab with "/" and "Group:\s+" with nothing.

Comment: @dandavis I did try that; unfortunately, it only handles the first instance of a subfolder. Because the parent folder names are then left in front of the first subfolder, there's no path provided for the remaining items. For example, I ended up with "Folder/Subfolder1" for the first instance, but the second one leaves "Subfolder2" with no path in front of it.

Comment: @zfrisch I think you're definitely on the right track; I'm now trying to give myself a crash-course in JS so I can figure out how to grab a parent folder name, and then prepend the parent name in each subsequent item which has a larger amount of white spaces. Then, iterate the process when the number of white spaces on the next line decreases. Not sure I described that the best way, but I think that's what you're suggesting.

Comment: @vertigozero1 I'll take a look at the problem a little more today. Just to be clear though, you need it properly formatted to folder\folder2\etc from the second example which is one long string? Or from the first which is nested with line breaks and spacing?

Comment: @zfrisch Thanks; any assistance would be greatly appreciated! That's right, it's the second example that's all one large string with no line breaks. 
To further complicate matters, the folder names can and frequently do contain spaces and other characters such as dashes, parentheses, and periods, so it can't just pick up on the first non-alphanumeric character after the end of a word and consider that a break.

Comment: @vertigozero1 I posted an answer. It takes into account spaces and other characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/362oapjk/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script> 

//on window load:
window.onload = function() {

//save input text into variable toBeParsed
//we wrap the <pre> tag to make sure variable text keeps all spaces/line breaks

var toBeParsed = "<pre> " + $("#input").html() + " </pre>"; 

//these next lines replace groups of space using regEx
//to format the text

toBeParsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{20}Group:\s)/g, "\\");
toBeParsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{16}Group:\s)/g, "\\");
toBeParsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{12}Group:\s)/g, "\\");
toBeParsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{8}Group:\s)/g , "\\");
var parsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{4}Group:\s)/g, "\n");

//insert parsed text into output section

$("#output").html(parsed);
}
</script> 
<pre><section id="input">
List of Folders
</section></pre>


<section id="output">
</section>
</html>
```

You paste the text into the section "input"

When you open the web page it takes the preformatted input text and parses like this:

1. Any match "Group: " with 20 spaces in front replaced with "\".
2. Any match "Group: " with 16 spaces in front replaced with "\".
3. Any match "Group: " with 12 spaces in front replaced with "\".
4. Any match "Group: " with 8 spaces in front replaced with "\".
5. Any match "Group: " with 4 spaces in front replaced with "\n" (newline).

The order is important because these are all intervals of 4. The reason why is because, as a faux example to understand the concept, if you were to parse for 4 spaces before 8 it would recognize it as 2 groups of 4 instead of 8.

This also means that it depends on what the longest sub folder string is. This code allows for up to 4 sub folders. If you need more you will need to add additional regex replacements. A.E. This is the code now:

```
toBeParsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{20}Group:\s)/g, "\\");
toBeParsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{16}Group:\s)/g, "\\");
toBeParsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{12}Group:\s)/g, "\\");
toBeParsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{8}Group:\s)/g , "\\");
var parsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{4}Group:\s)/g, "\n");
```

To add a fifth sub folder you would add another line with an additional 4 spaces(from 20 to 24) to replace, like this:

```
toBeParsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{24}Group:\s)/g, "\\");
toBeParsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{20}Group:\s)/g, "\\");
toBeParsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{16}Group:\s)/g, "\\");
toBeParsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{12}Group:\s)/g, "\\");
toBeParsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{8}Group:\s)/g , "\\");
var parsed = toBeParsed.replace( /(\s{4}Group:\s)/g, "\n");
```

Additionally, because the first "Group: Folder" in the string has no spaces before it you can add 4 spaces in the beginning of the input section to get a clean result. A.E.

```
//without spaces:
<pre><section id="input">Group: Folder        Group: SubFolder    Group: Folder2</section></pre>

//with spaces
<pre><section id="input">    Group: Folder       Group: SubFolder    Group: Folder2</section></pre>
```

And that should just about do the trick.

Comment: That helps immensely, especially your detailed description! From looking at this, I see why none of my hamfisted scripting attempts have worked so far. However, this solution doesn't take into account that the parent-level folders are only listed once, which is the real kicker. So, for the example input above, this script handles "Folder2" perfectly, but groups "SubFolder2" as a child of "SubFolder1" instead of having them both being directly under the same parent "Folder," if that makes sense.

Comment: @vertigozero1 haha, well glad it's starting to get better! But yes, I get what you mean (though it took me a minute) I'll work that out probably sometime today and tag you when I edit the answer. Sorry. I didn't quite understand before.